# upload file via ssh.Client and create path if no exists

Tags: bash, go

I'm trying to upload a file via ssh. The problem is that if the path not exists I need bash command to create directories paths.

let's say I want to upload the given file to `/etc/a/load.sh`

what `bash` command should I use instead of  `scp` as shound here - `buf.WriteString("sudo scp -t " + path + "\n")`

```
func upload(con *ssh.Client, buf bytes.Buffer, path string, content []byte) error {
    session, err := con.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer session.Close()

    buf.WriteString("sudo scp -t " + path + "\n")
    if err != nil {
        return &DeployError{
            Err:    err,
            Output: buf.String(),
        }
    }
    stdin, err := session.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    go func() {
        defer stdin.Close()
        fmt.Fprint(stdin, "C0660 "+strconv.Itoa(len(content))+" file\n")
        stdin.Write(content)
        fmt.Fprint(stdin, "\x00")
    }()

    output, err := session.CombinedOutput("sudo scp -t " + path)
    buf.Write(output)
    if err != nil {
        return &DeployError{
            Err:    err,
            Output: buf.String(),
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: why do you need `sudo` here?